# Set string from Parent-Form in UserControl error panel cast

Tags: c#

my Problem is when i try to declare my parent form it get´s an error which is:

```
System.InvalidCastException: "The object of type `System.Windows.Forms.Panel` cannot be converted to type "xxx.Form1".
```

I don´t know how to fix this, normally it works fine.
Parent-Form code is just a `public string EinstellungenGeändert` and my `UserControl` code is that:

```
        Form1 myParent = (Form1)this.Parent;
        myParent.EinstellungenGeändert = true;
```

Does someone know the reason or have a possible solution?

Comment: Are you sure the panel's parent is a `Form`? Chances are it's not. Do this: `Console.WriteLine(this.Parent.GetType().Name);` and tell me what it says.

Comment: A solution to this is to have a property on your panel called `public Form MainForm { get; set; }`, then from `Form1` constructor call `panel1.MainForm = this;`. This isn't the best way to go about it because you are tightly coupling `Form1` to `Panel1`, but you were doing that already by trying to grab the parent.

Comment: I tought so yes, it says:
Panel

But i really dont understand this..
Because i dont have any panel actually in my project.

Comment: Exactly, which is why you *shouldn't* be using `Parent`, or `Parent.Parent` or `Parent.Parent.Parent` to get a reference to your main form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that 'this.Parent' in your code refers to a type of 'System.Windows.Forms.Panel' which is not the same type as 'Form1'.

Are you sure your Form1 type is really 'this.Parent'? Try to go one level up (this.Parent.Parent) and then again if needed even though I don't know what you are trying to reach.

Comment: This doesn't answer his question. This is just a suggestion of what *may* fix the issue. For all you know, `Parent.Parent` could be another panel. And, is this really a solution to the problem? Are you really suggesting he should write code that looks like this? `var frm = (Form)this.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent;`

Comment: I'm not designing his program Andy.

Comment: But you should try to steer them in the right direction on *how* they should do this pattern. What if he adds another panel as a parent? This would break.